# Can't achieve simultaneous connections to a server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I have a java server (java 1.6, in case it helps) that accepts socket connections and then starts threads to resolve them, like any regular multithreading server. But I can't get to do a simultaneous connection. I connect a client that constantly sends and receive a message, and try to connect a second one, but the second one always returns a BindException telling me the address is already in use. Am I getting the whole multithreading thing wrong, be it either conceptually or in my code?

My server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocketUPMS1 = null;
    try {
        serverSocketUPMS1 = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(cfg.getProperty("UPMSServerPort")));
        serverSocketUPMS1.setSoTimeout(0);
        log.info("Starting the USSDInterface server at port "+serverSocketUPMS1.getLocalPort());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("The TCP server couldn't be started",e);
        finish = true;
    }

    while (!finish) {
            try {
                log.info("Waiting for a socket to connect...");
                Socket subscriberSocket = serverSocketUPMS1.accept();
                //Timeout de sesion ussd para poder crear una TimeoutException
                int timeOutSocket = Integer.parseInt(cfg.getProperty("USSDSocketTimeout"));
                log.info("New client arrived from " + subscriberSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                upms = new USSDSocket2(subscriberSocket,timeOutSocket);
                Thread t1 = new Thread(upms);
                t1.setName(Integer.toString(subscriberSocket.getLocalPort()) +","+ subscriberSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress() +", upms");
                t1.start();
                UPMSSimUtils.createAvailableInstance(upms);
                log.trace("USSD Socket created and initiated");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn("There's been an error while working with the server socket"+e.getMessage(), e);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    log.warn("There's been an error while waiting to resume the socket listenting"+e1.getMessage(), e1);
                }
            }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.warn("There's been an error while waiting in the server"+e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    try {
        serverSocketUPMS1.close();
        log.info("TCP Server is now DOWN");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("There was an error while closing the server socket. TCP Server is now DOWN",e);
    }
    upms.stop();
```

The processing thread:

```
public void run() {
    new Thread(new Sender()).start();
    while (!finish) {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[10000];
        byte size[] = new byte[4];
        try {
            this.socket.getInputStream().read(size, 0, 4);
            Integer largo = calcularTamanio(size);
            log.debug("Size in bytes: "+size);
            log.debug("Length of the incoming string: " + largo);
            this.socket.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0, largo);
            log.debug("Buffer of the incoming string: " + tostr2(buffer));
            decodeMessage(parseXML(toStr(buffer)), toStr(buffer));

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            log.error("Socket exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            this.finish = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IO exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            this.finish = true;
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            log.error("JDOM exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unknown exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            this.finish = true;
        }
        // try {
        // Thread.sleep(1);
        // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        // }
    }
    try {
        this.socket.close();
        this.socketUDP.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error closing the sockets at the USSDSocket", e);
    }
}
```

The creation of the client socket:

```
try{
                socketsCreated++;
                log.info("Attempting to create a socket");
                Properties properties=Config.getInstance().getCfg();

                ussdIface = new USSDInterfaceServerClass(properties);

                int port=Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("TestClientSocketTargetPort"));

                log.info("Client will connect to "+properties.getProperty("TestClientSocketTargetAddress")+":"+port);

                clientSocket = new Socket(properties.getProperty("TestClientSocketTargetAddress"),port);
                log.info("Socket connected");
                log.info("Client socket targeting "+properties.getProperty("TestClientSocketTargetAddress")+":"+port+" created");

                USSDSocket2 ussdSocket=new USSDSocket2(clientSocket,Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("USSDSocketTimeout")));
                UPMSSimUtils.createAvailableInstance(ussdSocket);

                upms = UPMSSimUtils.getAvailable(properties);

                Thread t1 = new Thread(ussdSocket);
                t1.setName("ussdsocket client test");
                t1.start();

                log.info("USSDSocket setted on the UPMSSimUtils");

                USSDSocketClientThread socketClientThread=instance.new USSDSocketClientThread(upms, "ClientSocketThread-"+socketsCreated);
                openSockets.add(socketClientThread);
                new Thread(socketClientThread).start();

                Thread.sleep(waitTimeBetweenConnections);
            }catch(Throwable throwable){
                log.warn("Error with a new connection",throwable);
                socketsCreated--;
            }
```

The only function that sends data through the socket:

```
public void send(String message) throws IOException {
    log.info("Trying to send message "+message);
    if (message != null && !"".equals(message)) {
        int largo = message.length();
        // largo = 800;
        byte largobytes[] = new byte[4];
        largobytes[0] = (byte) (largo % 256);
        largobytes[1] = (byte) (largo / 256);
        largobytes[2] = (byte) (largo & 0x00FF0000);
        largobytes[3] = 0;
        this.socket.getOutputStream().write(largobytes);
        log.trace("Byte length sent: "+largobytes);
        this.socket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());
        log.info("Message sent successfully");
    }
}
```

The processing thread is in charge of reading everything that comes through the socket. Then, decodeMessage creates a response that is sent through the same socket after processed. A different utilitary class allows me to send messages through the socket by making references to it and waiting for its responses.

I don't know if it's the way that I read from the input/output streams or what (does using the plain streams binds or blocks the socket?), but it's really vexing how every example seems to tell me that what I'm doing is ok, when it gives me those kind of errors.

Comment: Is `upms` a global variable? It seems so and if yes the second connection overwrites the `upms` and both client threads work withe the same socket.

Comment: 'upms' isn't a global variable, is a parameter of the thread class that's setted before the thread is started. Sorry, I should've clarified that. I'll correct it right now.

Comment: Getting a BindException is unusual during a client connect as your source port is ephemeral, so it should be unbound. Are you explicitly calling bind() on the socket when connecting? Can you post your client code? We need to see what it's doing if it's throwing an exception.

Comment: I added as much relevant info as I found. The whole thing is a bit of a mess so adding every piece of relevant info will be too much. But the thing is: I'm not doing any bind() whatsoever. Maybe there's a reason why it suddenly gets in a bind-like state?

Comment: The sleep in the accept loop is literally a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget every thing. The error was that the original maker of the code left a hardcoded socket initiating on a hardcoded port. Since the socket wasn't being used, I never noticed of its existance (I mistakenly assumed the stack trace of the error led to the actual working socket, but it wasn't so)